# How to add ' before and after strings in a new data frame column

Tags: python, string, dataframe

Given is the DataFrame like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'first name' : ['Max'], 'last name' : ['Miller']})
```

The goal is to get a new column "name" whoch contains two strings with ' separated by comma, e.g.

'Max' , 'Miller'

I tried it with, but this does not result in single strings.

```
df['name'] = df['first name'] + ',' + df['last name']
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm dubious that what you're asking for is really what you want, but this will do what you ask:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
        {'first name': ['Max'], 'last name': ['Miller']},
        {'first name': ['Joe'], 'last name': ['Jones']},
        {'first name': ['Tex'], 'last name': ['Smith']},
        {'first name': ['Bud'], 'last name': ['Ng']}
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

df['name'] = [f"'{a[0][0]}', '{a[1][0]}'"
    for a in zip(df['first name'], df['last name'])
]
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  first name last name
0      [Max]  [Miller]
1      [Joe]   [Jones]
2      [Tex]   [Smith]
3      [Bud]      [Ng]
  first name last name             name
0      [Max]  [Miller]  'Max', 'Miller'
1      [Joe]   [Jones]   'Joe', 'Jones'
2      [Tex]   [Smith]   'Tex', 'Smith'
3      [Bud]      [Ng]      'Bud', 'Ng'
```

But why do you want the names in single quotes, and why do you want the first name first?  Your example has "comma space" between the names, which I've done here.  That can be changed trivially.

Comment: My goal is to apply this function to the column "name" of my DataFrame: 

def compare_email_name(email, name):
    
    lower_name = str.lower(name)
    lower_email = str.lower(str.split(email,'@')[0])
    nopunc_email = re.sub('[!@#$%^&*()-=+.,]', ' ', lower_email)
    nonum_email = re.sub(r'[0-9]+', '', nopunc_email).strip()
    distance = round(Levenshtein.distance(lower_name,nonum_email) / len(email),1)
    return distance

Comment: So, you're trying to match email addresses to real names using Levenshtein distance? You should have said so from the start.  I'm not sure that's the right metric.  And you certainly don't want quotes or commas, as you said.  Most corporate environments use either "timr" or "troberts" or "tim.roberts", where a more simple check would work.  Non-corporate emails very often have nothing to do with the name.  You should ask another question where you say what your REAL overall goal is.